# Centering in TikZ matrix of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-matrix

I have a tabular-like matrix of nodes (with borders) defined in TikZ, however, despite setting `anchor=center` and `align=center` for all nodes, the text remains shifted to the left. I also tried `anchor=base`, but that didn't change anything (except getting a slight misalignment of nodes in my document, though not in the minimal example)

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [
            matrix of nodes,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            nodes={
                rectangle, draw=black, minimum height=1.25em, minimum width=1.25em,
                anchor=center, align=center,
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
            }
        ] {
            0 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Image showing alingment issue in minimal example]

Comment: The space after the numbers is not ignored. Use `0& 3& 6& 9& 12& 15& 18& 21\\`

Comment: @esdd thank you! if you post that as an anwer, I'll gladly accept it. what is the reasoning behind this (IMO) strange begavior?

Comment: See the answer of @Ignasi. It solves your problem really and explains the behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`align=center` without any `text width` is the problem. Comment it out and all text will be centered (with or without space after it) or add a `text width` over which the text could be centered.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [
            matrix of nodes,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            nodes={
                rectangle, draw=black, minimum height=1.25em, minimum width=1.25em,
                anchor=center, %align=center, %text width=2em,
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
            }
        ] {
            0 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what other bells and whistles you want in your real application but rather than using a `matrix of nodes` for this you might want to consider using a macro with an embedded for-loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=4mm]{standalone}

\newcommand\myarray[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#1} {
       \draw[thick](\c-0.5,0-0.5) rectangle ++ (1,1);
       \draw(\c,0)node{\x};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
   \myarray{0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

The main benefit of this approach is that it simplifies the code quite a lot, especially if you have a lot of these arrays. Of course, you can fine tune at will with shading, colours, font sizes, box size etc etc.

**EDIT**

Motivated by the OP's comment, here is a 2D version:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=4mm]{standalone}

\newcommand\myarray[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \row [count=\r] in {#1} {
      \foreach \x [count=\c] in \row {
        \draw[thick](\c-0.5,-\r-0.5) rectangle ++ (1,1);
        \draw(\c,-\r)node{\x};
       }
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
   \myarray{{0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21},{2,4,7,11},{4,5,6,7}}
\end{document}
```

This code produces:

[image]

Comment: As I need both the per-entry labels and 2-d arrays, rolling my own does not seem to be a good solution.

Comment: @joe Not sure which variation of a 2d array you want but I have added one possible variant.